# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnabl

Tags: android-app-bundle, flutter-release, bundletool

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key mlive from store "C:\khalid\New folder\mlive\android\app\mlive.jks": No key with alias 'mlive' found in keystore C:\khalid\New folder\mlive\android\app\mlive.jks

```
this my key.properties


 storePassword=mmmmmm
 keyPassword=mmmmmm
 keyAlias=mlive
 storeFile=mlive.jks
```

```
gradle.properties

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
app/build.gradle

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
          keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mlive"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    // buildTypes {
    //     release {
    //         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
    //         // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
    //         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    //     }
    // }
    signingConfigs {
       release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
          }
     }

     buildTypes {
         debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
     }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.9.0-alpha02'
}
```

i tried many solution on stack overflow but nothing works still getting error,many solution in not working ,i new in flutter development flutter gradle error . this is getting while relese the app , when build app bundle command its getting this

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that there is no key with the alias named `mlive` in the keystore.

To list the aliases available in the keystore, run the command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore mlive.jks
```

And search for the entry `Alias name: XXXXXX`

Whatever is in place of "XXXXXX" is the the alias you should specify.
Then, in your `key.properties` replace the name of the alias in the line `keyAlias=mlive`.